# R - split numerical values from units within a data frame column and append units to column name

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a sample data frame as follows:

```
df_test <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1:5),
  Length = c("17 mm","20 mm", "32 mm", "69 mm", "100 mm"),
  Vmax = c("17 cm2","20 cm2", "32 cm2", "69 cm2", "100 cm2"),
  Age = c("17 years","20 years", "32 years", "69 years", "100 years"),
  PG = c("17 mmHg","20 mmHg", "32 mmHg", "69 mmHg", "100 mmHg"),
  Weight = c("17 kg","20 kg", "32 kg", "69 kg", "100 kg")
)
```

I would like to identify the units in each column, append these units to the column name, and leave only numerical values. The result should look like this:

```
  ID Length_cm Vmax_cm2 Age_years PG_mmHg Weight_kg
1  1        17       17        17      17        17
2  2        20       20        20      20        20
3  3        32       32        32      32        32
4  4        69       69        69      69        69
5  5       100      100       100     100       100
```

I would then like to take this one step further by being able to specify which columns within a range I apply this rule to.

Using the following code, I am able to successfully complete this for a single specified column:

```
df_test$Vmax

units <- gsub(".* ", "", df_test$Vmax)
units <- units[!is.na(units)]
units <- unique(units)

df_test$Vmax <- as.numeric(gsub(" .*$", "", df_test$Vmax))

col_index <- which(colnames(df_test) == "Vmax")
col_name <- colnames(df_test)[col_index]

new_col_name <- paste(col_name, units, sep="_")
names(df_test)[col_index] <- new_col_name
```

I cannot work out how to apply this method to multiple columns. I have tried to put this into a for loop and use mutate(across()), with no success.

N.B. To clarify, the numerical values and units are always separated by a space. The units are consistent throughout any given column. There may also be some NA values within the column.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can reshape longer, then separate each measurement into a value and a unit, converting the numbers to numeric data, and then reshape wide, combining the original column name and the unit for the new names.

```
library(tidyr)
df_test %>%
  pivot_longer(-ID) %>%
  separate(value, c("val", "unit"), convert = TRUE) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(name, unit), values_from = val)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 5 x 6
     ID Length_mm Vmax_cm2 Age_years PG_mmHg Weight_kg
  <int>     <int>    <int>     <int>   <int>     <int>
1     1        17       17        17      17        17
2     2        20       20        20      20        20
3     3        32       32        32      32        32
4     4        69       69        69      69        69
5     5       100      100       100     100       100
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_test %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = "column", values_to = "value") %>% 
  separate(col = value, into = c("value", "unit")) %>% 
  
  transmute(
    ID, 
    column = str_c(column, unit, sep = "_"),
    value = as.numeric(value)
  ) %>% 
  
  pivot_wider(names_from = column, values_from = value) 

# A tibble: 5 × 6
     ID Length_mm Vmax_cm2 Age_years PG_mmHg Weight_kg
  <int>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1        17       17        17      17        17
2     2        20       20        20      20        20
3     3        32       32        32      32        32
4     4        69       69        69      69        69
5     5       100      100       100     100       100
```

Also, try lower_case + camel_case on colnames and avoid some trouble!

> There may also be some NA values within the column.

PS. Small edition to help with `NA` data.

Let´s say:

```
df_test <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1:5),
  Length = c("17 mm","20 mm", "32 mm", NA_character_, "100 mm"),
  Vmax = c("17 cm2","20 cm2", "32 cm2", "69 cm2", NA_character_),
  Age = c("17 years", NA_character_, NA_character_, "69 years", "100 years"),
  PG = c("17 mmHg","20 mmHg", "32 mmHg", "69 mmHg", "100 mmHg"),
  Weight = c(NA_character_,"20 kg", "32 kg", "69 kg", "100 kg")
```

If at least one value isn´t `NA`, `fill`, grouped by "column", will do the trick:

```
df_test %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = "column", values_to = "value") %>% 
  separate(col = value, into = c("value", "unit")) %>% 
  
  with_groups(column, \(x) fill(x, unit, .direction = "downup")) %>% 
  
  transmute(
    ID, 
    column = str_c(column, unit, sep = "_"),
    value = as.numeric(value)
  ) %>% 
  
  pivot_wider(names_from = column, values_from = value) 

# A tibble: 5 × 6
     ID Length_mm Vmax_cm2 Age_years PG_mmHg Weight_kg
  <int>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1        17       17        17      17        NA
2     2        20       20        NA      20        20
3     3        32       32        NA      32        32
4     4        NA       69        69      69        69
5     5       100       NA       100     100       100
```

Answer (score 0):

alternatively please try

```r
# get the units
nm <- sapply(df_test[,-1], \(x){ 
str_extract(x,'(?<=\\s).*')[1]
  })

# rename the variables with units
names(df_test)[2:6] <- paste(as.vector(names(df_test)[-1]),as.vector(nm),sep = '_')

# remove the units from variables
new_df <- map_df(df_test[,-1], \(x) {
  str_extract(x,'.*(?=\\s)')
})


# combine the ID with other variables
cbind(ID=df_test[,1],new_df)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
  ID Length_mm Vmax_cm2 Age_years PG_mmHg Weight_kg
1  1        17       17        17      17        17
2  2        20       20        20      20        20
3  3        32       32        32      32        32
4  4        69       69        69      69        69
5  5       100      100       100     100       100
```